# search for columns matching a variable

Tags: r

I have a simple question here actually, I have a matrix (file1) of data (say 20 columns by 100 rows). which looks like this

```
A    B    C    D    E    F ...  
5    6    2    3    4    5 ...
5    6    2    3    4    5 ...
5    6    2    3    4    5 ...
5    6    2    3    4    5 ...
5    6    2    3    4    5 ...
.    .    .    .    .    .
.    .    .    .    .    .
.    .    .    .    .    .
```

I have a variable named "R" which is

```
R <- c(A,C,E,F)
```

I want to make a new matrix (file2) which contains only columns that match the variable "R"

It should be a simple command I think, but I just couldn't find the right way to write this. 
Please note that the A B C D E F are colnames, not a first row.

cheers,

Comment: You must have searched *real* hard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
R = c("A","C","E","F");
file2 = file1[,R];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)
colnames(m) <- LETTERS[1:10]
myR <- c("A", "C", "D")
m2 <- m[,myR]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match columns names:

```
Dataset <- data.frame(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E,F=F)
R <- c("A","C","E","F")   
match(R,names(Dataset))
```

If actually your R contains the datasets A,C,E,F and since you might have a diferent name but the same list of values:

```
Dataset <- data.frame(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E,F=F)
R <- data.frame(A=A,C=C,E=E,FF)   
which(match(names(R),names(Dataset)) & match(R,Dataset))
```